# installing NUMPY for Mac OSX 10.7. (Lion) for use with Python

Tags: python, osx-lion, nltk

I need to use nltk and numpy with Python.  I am a newbie to Python and initially used the python 2.7.3 that came with my mac (currently running OSX 10.7.5).  I learned that the apple version of python may not be robust so I downloaded the standard version from python.org.

I have downloaded the nltk program for Mac OSX 10.7. This seemed to install fine. I am trying to download and install numpy using the instructions from the scipy website.  http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Mac_OS_X.

I cloned numpy from github but when I tried to build it using the following command

```
$ python setup.py build
```

I received the following error

> MacOS/Python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I also tried to build it using the scons command

```
$ python setupscons.py scons --jobs=2
```

and received the following error

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'setupscons.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Can anyone think of a possible workaround?

Comment: I would download the binaries linked to by numpy rather than try to compile it yourself

Comment: Or follow the instructions before they give scons as an alternative. scons is not a standard part of python or OSX e.f. the python setup.py lines

Comment: Sounds like you were not in the directory where setup.py is located?

Comment: I was working on the same thing the last few days, by the way. Do you have Xcode and its command line tools yet? MacPorts can also be useful.